# Changing directory with os in python

Tags: operating-system, cd

I'm trying to change the directory to the folder that contains the folder I'm in.

That is, I'm in /Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding/mpgdata and I'm trying to go back to /Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding and access a text file in the Coding folder.

When I run this code:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('⁨Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding')
```

I get this output and error

```
/Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding/mpgdata
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6c6ee01785f6> in <module>
      1 import os
      2 print(os.getcwd())
----> 3 os.chdir('⁨Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u2068Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding'
```

Does anyone know why this could be the case?

Edit: forgot to mention I am on a Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using C:\ in front of Users. If that does not work, try using .. in the directory specification to go back one directory.

Comment: .. worked! I didn't know you could use that command with os to go back a directory. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on a mac. How can I go forward in to the mpgdata folder? Adding C:\ didn't work.

Comment: I was able to do it with os.chdir("/Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding/mpgdata")

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes os.chdir("⁨Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding") instead of os.chdir('⁨Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding')

Comment: Are you using Windows? The accepted answer uses windows C:\ but you have forward slash which would denote Mac or Linux - not windows

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on a mac. How can I get back in to the mpg directory after I .. out of it?

Comment: A shortcut in the terminal to get back to the previous directory is "cd -"

Comment: I was able to do it with os.chdir("/Users/ethanfuerst/Documents/Coding/mpgdata")

Comment: I believe that is essentially what I wrote above.